# Pythonでアクティブウィンドウの取得をしたいのですが、プロセス名として取得したいのですがウィンドウ名として取得されてしまいます。

Tags: python, python3, winapi

現在Pythonを使ってアクティブウィンドウを取得し、1日にどのソフトにどれだけの時間をかけたのかを統計したいと考えております。
そこで希望しているデータが帰ってこないので質問させていただきました。

#### 現在使用しているプログラム

win32guiのライブラリを使用し`win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())`というコードを使用し、アクティブウィンドウの名前を取得

#### 現在使用しているプログラムから出力される結果

下の例がStringとして出力されている。

(例1) `ActiveWindow.py - Visual Studio Code`
(例2) `質問する - スタック・オーバーフロー - Google Chrome`

#### 希望している結果

希望している出力される結果は、上の例1でしたら`VisualStudio`のみ、例2の場合`Google Chrome`のみ

理由はGoogle Chromeを1日に合計1時間使用していたなどの統計を取りたいため。
これでも無理やり統計を取れると思いましたが、Adobeのillustratorのアクティブウィンドウを取得してみた結果、`名称未設定-1 @ 67.83% (RGB/プレビュー)` と表示されてしまい、Adobe Illustratorという文字すら表示されず、これでは統計が取れないと思い別の方法が必要でした。

#### 環境

Python 3.9.0
Windows 10

皆さんのお知恵をお貸しいただけますと大変助かります。是非よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 実行されているexeファイル名を取得するのはどうでしょう？ WMI系 [win32gui get the current active application name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14394513/9014308), [How to get Process name by Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42017669/9014308) psutil系 [Getting process name of focused window with python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65362756/9014308) の変種で一覧取得 [【コピペでOK】pythonで実行中のプロセス一覧を取得する方法](https://web-lh.fromation.co.jp/archives/10000047001), [Python：実行中のすべてのプロセスのリストと...](https://tech-branch.9999ch.com/archives/87) C++の話 [\[Win32 API\] ウィンドウハンドルから実行ファイル名取得...](https://qiita.com/kerupani129/items/e5cb4e6eece9956896a0)

Comment: おかげさまで解決できました。exeファイル名で取得する方法ありがとうございました。

Comment: 情報共有のために、解決策として採用した方法とか、そしてそれを適用して最終的にはどのような結果を得たかった(or得られた)のか、といった出来るだけのことを自己回答してみてください。

Comment: 以前はwin32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())を使ってアクティブウィンドウの表示されているテキストを取得していました。ですが質問内容の通りこの方法ではテキストを取得しているため、表示される方法に一貫性がありませんでした。
解決方法としてはご紹介いただいたプロセスを取得する方法[How to get Process name by Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017669/how-to-get-process-name-by-python)を参考にしました。
win32com.clientライブラリを使用し、現在実行中のプロセスを全て
取得し、ExecQuery('Select * from win32_process')でプロセスIDも取得できました。
実行中のプロセス一覧からアクティブウィンドウであるプロセスをif文で篩にかける為に
win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()をwin32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId()に代入してあげればプロセスのIDが取得できるようになりました。
以前はwin32gui.GetForegroundWindow()がプロセスIDだと勘違いしてました。